# PhD Student with Aufenthaltserlaubnis planning research visit for more than 3 months in another EU state (France)

Tags: germany, resident-permit, france, australian-citizens

I am an Australian citizen and currently live in Germany. I have an Aufenthaltserlaubnis (limited residence permit) valid until the end of my PhD contract. I am planning a research visit to an institute in France, however, for longer than 3 months. During this time,  I will still be enrolled at my institute in Germany, and be paid by them (and by extension, still pay german taxes / social security).

Is this possible with the German residency permit (Aufenthaltserlaubnis), or would I additionally need to apply for a residence permit in France? I was not able to find any information online - using this website  https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en_US/web/france-visas/  and inputting an Australian passport, it says I need a visa unless I am 'A foreign national who holds a long-term resident permit-EU from a state of the European Union'. However, I am not sure if the  Aufenthaltserlaubnis counts - it is a long term residency permit, but it has an expiry date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An '[EU long-term residence permit](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0146)' is the name of a **residence permit type**, which can be issued after 5 years of a normal residence.

Your residence permit card, in the field **type of permit**, should contain something in the form of

- **Daueraufenthalt-EU**

and in **remarks** it should start with: **9a** (based on §9a AufenthG).

If this is not the case, you may assume that you will need a french D-Visa.

---

[image]

- sample shown in image:

  - **type of permit**: *Aufenthaltserlaubnis*
  - **remarks**: *18 ABS 4* (based on *§ 18 (4) AufenthG*)

---

**Sources**:

- [§9a - EU long-term residence permit - AufenthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0146)

  - [EU long-term residence permit - Services - Dienstleistungen - Service Berlin - Berlin.de](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/324281/en/)

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. In short, the OP is neither eligible for Daueraufenthalt-EU, nor he needs a french D-Visa. I have already marked the question as duplicated.

Comment: @AndreySapegin You have complealy misread this answer. It clarifies what **long-term resident permit-EU** is and how he can check if he has it or not. Since the exact type of permit that he has is unknown, your claim that it is a duplicate cannot be varified. Kindly read the question and answer *properly* before making such claims and downvoting.

Comment: The question of the OP was "Is this possible with the German residency permit (Aufenthaltserlaubnis), or would I additionally need to apply for a residence permit in France?" Your answer indeed clarifies what a Daueraufenthalt-EU is, but it does not answer a question and provides misleading information ("you will need a french D-Visa").

Comment: @AndreySapegin The answer says that if doesn't have the residence permit type that his quote states exempts him from a visa, then `you may assume that you will need a french D-Visa.`. (you left the word **assume** out of your *partial* quote). This is a correct statement. Your statement, that he doesn't need a french visa, is questionable since you don't know what type of permit he presently has and therefore cannot determine if it exempts him from that requirement.